# React.js mouse, touch event not work only on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, touch-event

[React, javascript, CSS codes for this problem](https://codepen.io/evan-jin/pen/LYLVqmp?editors=0010)

I have some issues on my codepen codes and I was supposed to paste my codes but it is too long to paste here so I leave my few codes here for somebody who can't get to my link and my full codes is on my link! plus you can see the output screen on the below the link!

[Output screen](https://codepen.io/evan-jin/full/LYLVqmp)

```
const { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useRef } = React
const INITIAL_PERCENT = 10
const MAX_PERCENT = 90

const App = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef()
  const barRef = useRef()
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    isSliding: false,
    currentPercent: INITIAL_PERCENT
  })
  
  function getPercent(clientX) {
    const dims = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
    return ((clientX - dims.left) / dims.width) * 100
  }
  
  const onMouseDown = useCallback(e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (info.isSliding === true) return
    console.log('mouse down')
    const percent = getPercent(e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX)
    setInfo({
      isSliding: true,
      currentPercent: percent > MAX_PERCENT ? MAX_PERCENT : percent
    }, () => {
      barRef.current.style.transition = 'none'
    })
  }, [info.isSliding])
  
  const onMouseMove =  useCallback(e => {
    const percent = getPercent(e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX)
    setInfo(state => ({
      ...state,
      currentPercent: (percent > MAX_PERCENT) ? MAX_PERCENT : 
                      (percent < INITIAL_PERCENT) ? INITIAL_PERCENT : percent
    }))
  }, [])
  
  const onMouseUp =  useCallback(e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('mouse up')
    const percent = getPercent(e.clientX || e.changedTouches[0].clientX)
    setInfo(state => ({
      ...state,
      isSliding: false,
      currentPercent: (percent > MAX_PERCENT) ? MAX_PERCENT : INITIAL_PERCENT
    }))
  }, [])
  
  // Resizing Width Animation starts only if mouse is up
  useEffect(() => {
    if (info.isSliding === false) {
      barRef.current.classList.add('slide')
    } else {
      barRef.current.classList.remove('slide')
    }
  }, [info.isSliding])
  
  // Animation for 100% compeleted
  useEffect(() => {
    if (info.isSliding === false && info.currentPercent >= MAX_PERCENT) {
      barRef.current.classList.add('complete')
    } else {
      barRef.current.classList.remove('complete')
    }
  }, [info.isSliding, info.currentPercent])
  
  // added 'passive -> false' to prevent touchstart fires twice on Mobile screen.
  useEffect(() => { 
    containerRef.current.addEventListener('touchstart', onMouseDown, { passive: false })
    return () => containerRef.current.removeEventListener('touchstart', onMouseDown, { passive: false })
  }, [])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (info.isSliding === true) {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
      window.addEventListener('touchmove', onMouseMove);
      window.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
      window.addEventListener('touchend', onMouseUp);
    }
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
      window.removeEventListener('touchmove', onMouseMove);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);;
      window.removeEventListener('touchend', onMouseUp);
    }
  }, [info.isSliding])
  
  return (
    <div className='wrapper'>
      <div className='states-info'>
        isSliding : {String(info.isSliding)} <br />
        currentPercent : {parseInt(info.currentPercent)}
        
      </div>
      <div className='container' onMouseDown={onMouseDown} ref={containerRef}>
        <div className='bar' ref={barRef} style={{width: `${info.currentPercent}%`}} />
        <div className='btn' />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/>, document.getElementById("root") )
```

My problem is that React slide bar css transition works perfectly on Desktop website and plus mobile version in F12 develop mode, so I was expecting it should work on my phone (IOS) but the animation(transition Width) doesn't work at all even though I didn't check out on Android mobile.

If it works perfectly on the desktop, then there might be a solution for this problem but I could't find it for a few days... I need to make it work on Mobile. please anybody check my code and help me please. thank you!

Comment: It's working fine on android.

Comment: @BilalMohammad thanks for checking, but does it have an animation on Android? bcuz Sliding works fine functionally but not with animation effect :(

Comment: Yes on my Oneplus it is working same as it is working on desktop site.

Comment: @BilalMohammad Oh I see then that must be a problem with IOS mobile! I really appreciate and I need to approach in other way. thank you

Comment: @BilalMohammad I solve the IOS problem by adding { capture: true } on addEventListener and removeEventListener as an option! thanks

Comment: Well , that's great.

Answer (score 2):

It's solved by adding { capture: true } on addEventListener and removeEventListener as an option!
I'm gonna keep this question for somebody who need this in the future!

Comment: it's strange that made a difference here, but it's good you've found workaround

Comment: Really?? Like how??

Comment: if this is a question, I don't know ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @skyboyer Oh I mean I could try to find why that makes difference on your devices. Like not showing animation on your mobile or something like that?